# Can't run apt update because apt-config is running in the background

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

I can't update my system anymore because some variation of apt-config is running in the background. 'ps aux | grep apt' shows one of the following two constantly running in the background. Also I can't kill these programs because the PID is constantly changing. Also another note, a user called '_apt' seems to be running these programs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
apt-config shell MASTER_KEYRING APT::Key::MasterKeyring
apt-config shell TRUSTEDPARTS Dir::Etc::TrustedParts/d
```

Comment: If you are using Debian and not and official "Ubuntu" release, then this question belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com as questions about Debian are off topic on Askubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have unattended-upgrades installed?

Answer (score 1):

From the `man apt-config` page:

```
   apt-config is an internal program used by various portions of the APT suite to provide
   consistent configurability. It accesses the main configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf in a
   manner that is easy to use for scripted applications.
```

Therefore, you should find out the parent process of each `apt-config` process.

Do

```
for i in $( pgrep apt-config ) ; do ps -fp$i; done
```

and look at the `PPID` column.

Answer (score 0):

`unattended-upgrades` runs `apt-daily` and `apt-daily` runs `apt-config`. You can disable automatic updates by running the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/1/0/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
sudo sed -i 's/1/0/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10perodic
```

source:

[wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)

On Debian, the periodic file is not the same:

```
sudo sed -i 's/1/0/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02perodic
```